# Add auto increment to existing column without affecting current record values

Tags: mysql

I would like to change the column type to `AUTO_INCREMENT` within an existing `MyISAM1` database table. The databse currently has thousands of records where the column value is very important. It is crucial that the current value is not affected. I want to increment from the latest higheste value.

I tried this within phpmyadmin (sql generated by phpmyadmin) and got an error.

```
ALTER TABLE `myTable` CHANGE `myCol1` `myCol1` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

The error I got was:

```
 ALTER TABLE causes auto_increment resequencing, resulting in duplicate entry '2197' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I did some reaserch and found that by adding an offset it should resolve my issue. I tried this but was greeted with a syntax error.

```
ALTER TABLE `myTable` CHANGE `myCol1` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT = 2500
```

error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT = 2500' at line 1
```

I have also tried the above sql without declaring INT

Simply put I need to keep the existing records as they are but add auto increment ability to column `myCol1` starting from number 2500 (as currently the last item is 2498). This column is also the Primary Key.

This is not a duplicate question as the solutions I have found for other answers do not resolve my issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using wrong syntax, try below command-

```
ALTER TABLE `myTable` CHANGE `myCol1` `myCol1` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, auto_increment=2500;
```