# How to add AUTO_INCREMENT to an existing table

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I'm new asking questions so I will appreciate if somebody can help me.

I have a MySQL DB created using Workbench, my database is already completed with all the relations, triggers, etc. but forgot to add the property "AUTO_INCREMENT" to one table's id PK. By the time I realized about this the database had already  values in all the tables, they are linked and in use.

I want to start the auto_increment to start at 100 at the same time I alter the table to add the property so the data don't overlap, I have already tried the following:

**ALTER TABLE core.ExtGroups 
CHANGE COLUMN ext_IdGroup ext_IdGroup INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT; 
Resulting on the following error -> "ERROR 1062: ALTER TABLE causes auto_increment resequencing, resulting in duplicate entry '1' for key PRIMARY"

**ALTER TABLE core.ExtGroups AUTO_INCREMENT = 100; (no error but does not work)

another idea I had was to create a "before insert" trigger to get the count(*) of rows and generate the next id value based on the result but I wouldn't rather to go that way...

Any ideas you can give me without dropping the table? That would cost me a lot of work

Comment: This question already has an answer. [Add auto increment to existing column without affecting current record values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34590200/add-auto-increment-to-existing-column-without-affecting-current-record-values)

Comment: Awesome, Thanks Ben, I fixed it!!!